show video after completing gravity form
I have a page with a button. When the user clicks on the button, a pop-up should open and he should enter his contact number using gravity form and then the video will be shown to him.
Now I have a button on the page and an html element that displays the video through the iframe tag, and the default mode is display: none.
function custom_script() {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // Event listener for form submission
        jQuery(document).on('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(event, formId){
            // Check if the submitted form is the one with ID 1
            if (formId == 1) {
                // Show the video element with ID 'wb-video'
                document.getElementById('wb-video').style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    });
    
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_script');

I put this code at the end of the functions.php file. But after the user completes the form, nothing happens on the page. The video is not displayed.
Thank you if you guide me.

What have you done to debug this? Try adding a console.log() after each line. Are you sure the gform_confirmation_loaded event is happening? Are there errors in your dev console? Can't really help you without that information.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The easy option to use here instead of code is to add a redirect URL after form submission in the gravity form setting and on that page, you can add the video you want to show to the user.
This way you will not have to add script on the website.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
